# Opening case (hyperlink) in primary tab

Tags: formula, case, hyperlink

I have a page on console where case number is shown as hyperlink. When it is clicked it should open in the same tab which is primary tab. I created formula field using Hyperlink function.It is opening the case in new tab. How can I show the case in the same tab?

```
HYPERLINK('https://dev2.salesforce.com/console?tsid=02u50000000VVyQ#%2F'+ id,Casenumber)
```

I tried using _self,_top,_parent as third parameter, But they did not give me the result as I desired

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject javacript to open the record in same tab.

Here is an example

```
HYPERLINK("javascript:if(typeof(srcUp)=='function') {srcSelf('/" & Id & "');} "+ 
" else {window.location.href='/" & Id & "'}" 
,Casenumber 
, "_self" 
)
```

For more information, refer my blog. [Different ways of navigation](http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/different-ways-of-navigation.html)

**Update**

As per comment, take this approach, for create a Custom Button or Link executing JavaScript

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/28.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/support/console/28.0/integration.js")} 
var url = '/apex/VisualforcePage'; 
if (sforce.console.isInConsole()) { 
navigateToUrl(url + '?inline=1'); 
} else { 
window.open(url,'_self'); 
}
```

Comment: I heard Javascript is not supported in hyperlink in formula field. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000249336&type=1

Comment: Then you can do Create a Custom Button or Link executing JavaScript or Create a custom Visualforce Page to redirect to the correct URL